# How can I install ElementaryOS on a 2012 Retina MacBook Pro?

Tags: linux, macos, installation, macbook, macbook-pro-retina

I'm interested in abandoning OS X in favour of ElementaryOS, a Linux distribution.

Before I do that, I want to know about any "gotchas" which would make installing Linux on a Retina MacBook Pro different from installing it on other hardware.

The two possible hangup points in my mind are:

- The proprietary bootloader
- The lack of an optical drive (I've already `dd`-ed the installation `.iso` onto a flash drive)

I'd like to know if these are indeed things to worry about, and how (if?) I can get around them. I'd also like to know if there's anything else I should look out for during the installation.

My OS X version is 10.11.5.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you made the installation media properly, you should have no issues installing ElementaryOS on your MacBook Pro.

Here are [directions](https://elementary.io/docs/installation#installation) from the ElementaryOS website.